# How do I get this update command to work in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, visual-studio-2017

I have a gridview that properly pulls the data as I need it. I have it set to custom queries since I am using stored procedures to update and delete the info. I am running a delete command and an update command, but only the delete command works.

My update command seems to be set up correctly, but when I change the name of one of the items and click update, the grid goes back to where it was before without the change. I also do not get an error message, so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot this. I've scoured the net trying to find an answer, but none seem to work for this situation. Is it possible the "original" parameters are causing an issue? I want the grid to take the old value as the check in the table. If this is causing the issue, is there another way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Here is my gridview code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvArtists"
            runat="server"
            AllowPaging="True"
            AllowSorting="True"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            DataSourceID="gridView_Artists"
            CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover"
            OnPreRender="gvArtists_PreRender"
            OnRowDeleted="gvArtists_RowDeleted"
            OnRowUpdated="gvArtists_RowUpdated">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="artist_FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" 
                    SortExpression="artist_FirstName" ItemStyle-CssClass="col-xs-3" >
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="col-xs-3"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="artist_LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" 
                    SortExpression="artist_LastName" ItemStyle-CssClass="col-xs-3" >
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="col-xs-3"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="artist_band" HeaderText="Band" 
                    SortExpression="artist_band" ItemStyle-CssClass="col-xs-3" >
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="col-xs-3"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="artist_type" HeaderText="Type" 
                    SortExpression="artist_type" ItemStyle-CssClass="col-xs-3" >
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="col-xs-3"></ItemStyle>
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:CommandField CausesValidation="False" ShowEditButton="True">
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="col-xs-1 text-danger" />
                </asp:CommandField>
                <asp:CommandField CausesValidation="False" ShowDeleteButton="True">
                    <ItemStyle CssClass="col-xs-1" /> 
                </asp:CommandField>
            </Columns>
            <HeaderStyle CssClass="bg-halloween" />
            <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altRow" />
            <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" />
            <PagerStyle CssClass="pagerStyle" BackColor="#a8c8c8c" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <EditRowStyle CssClass="warning" />
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource 
            ID="gridView_Artists" 
            runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:disk_inventoryConnectionString %>"
            ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues"
            SelectCommand="SELECT artist_FirstName,
                artist_LastName,
                artist_band,
                artist_type
            FROM ArtistInfo
            ORDER BY artist_LastName"
            DeleteCommand="sp_DeleteArtistInfo"
            DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure"
            UpdateCommand="sp_UpdateArtistInfo"
            UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="artist_FirstName" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="artist_LastName" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="artist_band" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="artist_type" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
            </DeleteParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="artist_FirstName"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="artist_LastName"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="artist_band"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="artist_type"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_artist_FirstName"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_artist_LastName"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_artist_band"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_artist_type"></asp:Parameter>
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Here is my stored procedures for update:

```
    create proc sp_UpdateArtistInfo
(
    @artist_FirstName varchar(50),
    @artist_LastName    varchar(50),
    @artist_band    varchar(50),
    @artist_type    varchar(50),
    @original_artist_FirstName  varchar(50),
    @original_artist_LastName   varchar(50),
    @original_artist_band   varchar(50),
    @original_artist_type   varchar(50)
)
as
    begin
    --start error checking
        begin try
            update ArtistInfo
                set 
                    artist_FirstName = @artist_FirstName,
                    artist_LastName = @artist_LastName,
                    artist_band = @artist_band,
                    artist_type = @artist_type
            WHERE   artist_FirstName = @original_artist_FirstName
                AND artist_LastName = @original_artist_LastName
                AND artist_band = @original_artist_band
                AND artist_type = @original_artist_type
            --display the change
        end try
        begin catch
            print error_message()
        end catch
    end
go
```

and for delete:

```
    create proc sp_DeleteArtistInfo
(
    @artist_FirstName varchar(50),
    @artist_LastName    varchar(50),
    @artist_band    varchar(50),
    @artist_type    varchar(50)
)
as
    begin
    --start error checking
        begin try
            DELETE FROM DiskHasArtist
            FROM    DiskHasArtist INNER JOIN
                    ArtistInfo ON DiskHasArtist.artist_ID = ArtistInfo.artist_ID
            WHERE   ArtistInfo.artist_FirstName = @artist_FirstName
                AND ArtistInfo.artist_LastName = @artist_LastName
                AND ArtistInfo.artist_band = @artist_band
                AND ArtistInfo.artist_type = @artist_type
            delete from ArtistInfo
            WHERE   artist_FirstName = @artist_FirstName
                AND artist_LastName = @artist_LastName
                AND artist_band = @artist_band
                AND artist_type = @artist_type
        end try
        begin catch
            print error_message()
        end catch
    end
go
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. I did not include the property "OldValuesParameterFormatString" so the app knows to pass my "original_" parameters.

Here is the new code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
            ID="gridView_Artists" 
            runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:disk_inventoryConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT artist_FirstName,
                artist_LastName,
                artist_band,
                artist_type
            FROM ArtistInfo
            ORDER BY artist_LastName"
            DeleteCommand="sp_DeleteArtistInfo"
            DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure"
            UpdateCommand="sp_UpdateArtistInfo"
            UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure"
            OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"
            ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues">
            <DeleteParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_artist_FirstName" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_artist_LastName" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_artist_band" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_artist_type" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
            </DeleteParameters>
            <UpdateParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="artist_FirstName"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="artist_LastName"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="artist_band"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="artist_type"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_artist_FirstName"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_artist_LastName"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_artist_band"></asp:Parameter>
                <asp:Parameter Name="original_artist_type"></asp:Parameter>
            </UpdateParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The **OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"** part tells the app to use the parameters.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't see why you additionally need that new line: OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}"   You already seemed to be providing all 8 of the update parameters required.  Aah, I see now:  your original information parameters are not defined in the gridview!! Phew!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.oldvaluesparameterformatstring?view=netframework-4.8.1